# Place a CollectionView item centrally

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In the `CollectionView` I have about 10 elements, populated with objects of my class which contains a property of type `DateTime`.

```
public class MyCalendar
{
    public DateTime Datet { get; set; }
}
```

The objects of the class I have inserted them in the `Observablecollection<MyCalendar> OCCalendar`

And in the `CollectionView` I have inserted the `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource`

Next I look for the object inside the `ObservableCollection` with `DateTime` property and compare it with `DateTime.Now.Date` to look for the one with `DateTime` on today's date. It finds it, and I try to insert it in a central position, but the `CollectionView` doesn't move.

```
ColCalendar.ItemsSource = OCCalendar;

var GiornoCorrente = OCCalendar.Where(x => x.Datet.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).First();
ColCalendar.ScrollTo(GiornoCorrente, position: ScrollToPosition.Center);
```

The `CollectionView` has enough elements to scroll both left and right

Comment: find one sample that you can take a look;https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Scrolling/ScrollToByObjectPage.xaml

Answer (score 0):

> Next I look for the object inside the ObservableCollection with DateTime property and compare it with DateTime.Now.Date to look for the one with DateTime on today's date. It finds it, and I try to insert it in a central position, but the CollectionView doesn't move.

You just have 10 items in Collectionview, I guess that the collectionview don't need to scrollto, these items will display in the screen.

**The ScrollToPosition.Center member indicates that the item should be scrolled to the center of the view, Just like you use the scroll wheel of a mouse to scroll a specific item to a specific position.**

```
<StackLayout>
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            Text="scrollto" />
        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label HeightRequest="30" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding time}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{        
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                  
        this.BindingContext = new scrollviewmodel();
    }
    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scrollviewmodel viewmodel = BindingContext as scrollviewmodel;
        scrollmodel item = viewmodel.models.FirstOrDefault(m => m.time.Date == DateTime.Now.Date);
        collectionView.ScrollTo(item, position: ScrollToPosition.Center);       
    } 
}

public class scrollviewmodel
{
    public ObservableCollection<scrollmodel> models { get; set; }
    public scrollviewmodel()
    {
        models = new ObservableCollection<scrollmodel>()
        {
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 1", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 2", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 3", time = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 4", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 5", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 6", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 7", time = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 8", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 8", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 10", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 12", time = new DateTime(2021, 3, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 13", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) }, 
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date s", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 7c", time = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 8v", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 8b", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 1n0", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 12n", time = new DateTime(2021, 3, 2) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 13h", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 4", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date a", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 5", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 6", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 7", time = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 8", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 8", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 10", time = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 12", time = new DateTime(2021, 3, 1) },
            new scrollmodel() { Name = "date 13", time = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) }
        };
    }
}
public class scrollmodel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public DateTime time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by putting the code inside the OnAppearing() method, while inside the constructor it was not working correctly, I don't know the reason

Comment: @signalover Yes, as my code, you can also put collectionView.ScrollTo in Button.click, it also works fine. maybe you can not call ScrollTo immediately after setting the binding.

Comment: in fact through the button or the OnAppearing() method it works, while in the constructor it doesn't